# Highcharts - persist tooltip outside pie chart on clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

How do I persist a tooltip outside the pie chart on clicking one of the pies.

The idea is that on clicking one of the pie in the pie chart rotates that pie to the bottom and the tooltip should be displayed outside the chart. It should be a click event and the mouse hover should not work.
The tooltip info should change when I click another just like how hover works

http://jsfiddle.net/ohfjyhj1/

```
$(function () {

function moveToPoint(clickPoint){
  var points = clickPoint.series.points;
  var startAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var p = points[i];
    if (p == clickPoint)
    {
      break;
    }
    startAngle += (p.percentage/100.0 * 360.0);
  }
  clickPoint.series.update({
    //startAngle: -startAngle + 180 // start at 180
    startAngle: -startAngle + 180 - ((clickPoint.percentage/100.0 * 360.0)/2) // center at 180
  });
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter:function(){
        $('#tooltip').html(this.y);
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            point:{
              events:{
                click: function(){
                  moveToPoint(this);
                }
              }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            ['Chrome',    12.8],
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
    }]
}, 
function(){
  var maxPoint = null;
  $.each(this.series[0].points, function(i,j){
    if (maxPoint === null || j.percentage > maxPoint.percentage){
      maxPoint = j;
    }
  });
  moveToPoint(maxPoint);
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/8VTTH/

```
  (function (H) {
H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (proceed, point, e) {
    if (e.type !== 'mousemove') {
        proceed.call(this, point, e);
    }
});
H.addEvent(H.Point.prototype, 'click', function (e) {
    e.point.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(e.point, e);
});
```

}(Highcharts));

How do I integrate the second fiddle part with the first.

Comment: But what exactly is wrong with your first jsFiddle? Do you even need second part? Just disable tooltip (`tooltip.enabled = false`) and then update your outer tooltip on click: http://jsfiddle.net/ohfjyhj1/1/

Comment: @PawełFus   Oh sweet! Thanks :) I totally missed the part about the point events.
Also just wondering Can this rotation be animated on click. Its pretty abrupt right now

Comment: Sure, but it will require some hacks for Highcharts. Instead of using `series.update()` you need to upadte `startAngle` in options, then call dummy `point.update()` to apply changes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ohfjyhj1/2/ Note: it doesn't look for the closest angle, but for the same points it's always the same rotation.